# npm version "scripts have access to the new version in package.json"

Tags: git, npm, version

The doco for `npm version` is at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version.

It says (my emphasis):

4. Run the version script. **These scripts have access to the new version in package.json (so they can incorporate it into file headers in generated files for example)**. Again, scripts should explicitly add generated files to the commit using git add.

How do you get this version from package.json.  With a combination of `grep, tr, ..` shell commands or in a variable?  I tried `%s` that is used for the `git tag` and `$npm.version` and `$npm_package_version` but none worked.

I ended up using this, which works well:

```
 "script": {
 ....
 "postversion": "version=$(git-semver-tags | head -1); echo \"export const config = { version: '$version' }\" > client/src/app/config-from-npm.ts",
 ....
 }
```

**EDIT** note that I changed the above from 'version' to 'postversion' since the new `git tag` is not available until after version and I changed to `git-semver-tags` since `git tags` lists them lexically (so 0.0.1 comes before 0.0.20).

My solution shows that I had to use `git-semver-tags`.  The question is - Is there a proper way to get the version from package.json as the doco states?

I feel that the doco should be updated.  I thought i'd create an issue against the https://github.com/npm/cli project but there is no 'issues' link (at least for me).  It is a new git repository after a recent move from a different project so perhaps someone forgot to tick that box!

---

(Edit) I have a separate question for how to write .json/.js/.ts files from NPM.  [How to output JSON in NPM Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56179801/how-to-output-json-in-npm-script) (now solved).

Comment: Did you edit your question to turn it into an answer? I.e. the code shown now actually works? Please don't do that. Make an answer instead and roll-back your latest edit.

Comment: No, I just refined the solution I had found (since what I had was incorrect.  If someone happened upon this and there was no sufficient answer then I would want to give them a correct solution to the problem).  It still stands that question is 'Is there a proper way to get the version from package.json as the doco states?' :)